# Range Check calling OpenSCManager in Alexandria 64-Bit

Tags: delphi, winapi, 64-bit, delphi-11-alexandria, range-checking

We recently updated from Delphi Berlin to Alexandria 11.2 and have run into an issue. One of our applications targets the 64-bit platform. When it goes connect query Windows services, it throws a range check error. It does not do this when targeting 32-bit; nor did this occur in Berlin/64-bit. I have compared the 64-bit compiling options between both environments and saw no differences.

```
function TForm1.ConnectToServices(const AServiceName: String; const AMachineName: String): Integer;
begin
  Result := -1;
  try
    if AMachineName = EmptyStr then
      // Error happens here
      Result := OpenSCManager(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT)
    else
      // and here.
      Result := OpenSCManager(PChar(AMachineName), nil, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
  except
    // Get last error return 0, but ignoring the above error causes problems downstream
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  end;
end;
```

I am truly at a loss for what is causing this and how to resolve it.

Setting the 64-bit compiler options to match those of Berlin where the dll call succeeds without issue.

Comment: It means the 64-bit handle returned by OpenSCManager won't fit in 32 bits. Delphi 11.2 did add support for the high entropy memory allocator so memory allocations are much less likely to have the top 32 bits all zeroes causing errors when trying to stuff them in 32-bit variables. Perhaps this affects some handles as well. Only handles that would be shared across processes have the top 32 bits all zeros.

Comment: @Brian That's it. Thank you very much. It'll be a pain to find all of places that whose handle types need to change, but at least I see the issue, now. If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows

Comment: `OpenSCManager()` returns an `SC_HANDLE` (alias for `THandle` in Delphi), not an `Integer`.  If you had been using the correct type to begin with, you wouldn't be having this problem. Your function needs to return a `THandle` preferably, or at least a `Native(U)Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:
The 64-bit handle returned by `OpenSCManager()` doesn't fit in a 32-bit integer.

Longer answer:

In Windows, handles are `VOID pointers` (`THandle` in Delphi), which means for 32-bit code they are 4 bytes and for 64-bit code they are 8 bytes. When handles need to be shared across processes, the top 4 bytes of the 8-byte handles are all zeros. This lets them be used by 32-bit and 64-bit processes. For 64-bit code, handles that are not shared between processes can use all 64 bits.

Starting with Delphi 11.2, by default the high entropy memory allocator is enabled. This means that any memory address, even in programs that do not use much memory, will usually not have the top 32 bits set to all zeros, so they won't fit in a 32-bit variable. Passing a 64-bit address through a 32-bit variable was always a bug, but now such errors are triggered much more readily.